# QPixmap load segmentation fault

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating a Qt Console Application on windows 7. I am using Qt 5.3.
And currently I have error that make me frustration because of it.
Already check on the stackoverflow, but no answers help me.

My problem was when creating a Qpixmap I got error segmentation fault and I don't have any other error information about it.

Here my code :

```
QString filePath = (directory + xmlReader.attributes().value("relativepath").toString());
QFile _file(filePath);
if (!_file.exists())
{
    qWarning() << "Error : file " << filePath << " does not exist";
    return false;
}

QImageReader imageReader(filePath);
QImage mainImage = imageReader.read();
if(mainImage.isNull())
{
    qWarning() << "Error read image : " << filePath;
    qWarning() << imageReader.errorString();
    return false;
}
QPixmap mainPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(mainImage)); // Segmentation fault here
```

On the last line of those code that generate the segmentation fault error on my machine.
Is there anything i can do to debug this error?

Update :
I have some code on QPixmap, but it lead the same segmentation fault.

Code 1 :

```
QString filePath = (directory + xmlReader.attributes().value("relativepath").toString());
QFile _file(filePath);
if (!_file.exists())
{
    qWarning() << "Error : file " << filePath << " does not exist";
    return false;
}

QImageReader imageReader(filePath);
QImage mainImage = imageReader.read();
if(mainImage.isNull())
{
    qWarning() << "Error read image : " << filePath;
    qWarning() << imageReader.errorString();
    return false;
}    
QPixmap mainPixmap;
mainPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(mainImage); // segmentation fault here
```

Code 2 :

```
QString filePath = (directory + xmlReader.attributes().value("relativepath").toString());
QFile _file(filePath);
if (!_file.exists())
{
    qWarning() << "Error : file " << filePath << " does not exist";
    return false;
}
QPixmap mainPixmap;
mainPixmap.load(filePath); // segmentation fault here
```

Code 3 :

```
QString filePath = (directory + xmlReader.attributes().value("relativepath").toString());
QFile _file(filePath);
if (!_file.exists())
{
    qWarning() << "Error : file " << filePath << " does not exist";
    return false;
}
QPixmap mainPixmap;
if(_file.open(QFile::ReadOnly))
{
    mainPixmap.loadFromData(_file.readAll()); //segmentation fault here
}
```

Comment: Move the `QPixmap::fromImage(mainImage)` to a separate line so you can try to determine whether it's that code or the `QPixmap` constructor.

Comment: Hm strange, perhaps the image is corrupt or invalid in some way. Are you using the debug versions of the Qt libraries? Do you have a callstack for when the crash occurs?

Comment: Try to specify file format

Comment: @sam : The image is OK, if if corrupt on the first code the the mainImage should be null, but it is not. And I check the png file has no problem when opened with other application.
Call stack stopped at the segmentation fault line.
t3ft3l : Already test it, but it has the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have figured out what is the problem.
The problem is I need to have QGuiApplication instance before using the QPixmap.

On console application I usually has QCoreApplication as the root QApplication, but when we want to use QPixmap we need to change it to QGuiApplication on main.cpp.

Hope this help others. :)

Comment: Thanks for the update. I would have thought there would be an assert or error message about this requirement. Perhaps next time try running with the debug libraries. Also next time post the callstack; it can help with debugging!